# CSS selector to select the first element after n elements

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Is there a way to select the first element with a some class after `n` elements? For example in the following HTML, I want to be able to select only the first `div` that has CSS class `apple` after the `5th` `div`, resulting in the `7th` `div` element being selected.

```
<div>
    <div class="data-class">1</div>
    <div class="data-class">2</div>
    <div class="data-class">3</div>
    <div class="data-class apple">4</div>
    <div class="data-class">5</div>
    <div class="data-class">6</div>
    <div class="data-class apple">7</div>
    <div class="data-class apple">8</div>
    <div class="data-class">9</div>
    <div class="data-class apple">10</div>
</div>
```

This selector selects all the `div`s, but I only want the first: `.data-class.apple:nth-child(n+5)`

And this one doesn't even work: `.data-class.apple:nth-child(n+5):first-child`

I have put the HTML and CSS samples [here](http://jsbin.com/xufoj/1/edit?html,css,js).

**UPDATE**
Current CSS selectors

```
.data-class{
  background-color: #0ea;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #444;
}

.data-class:nth-child(n+5)+.apple{
  background-color: #f0f;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To select an element appearing after some other element, use the `~` combinator:

```
.data-class:nth-child(5) ~ .data-class.apple {
  background-color: #f0f;
}
```

You won't be able to match only the first `.apple` that occurs using just one selector. You will need to create another rule to undo the styles that you apply for subsequent `.apple` elements:

```
.data-class:nth-child(5) ~ .data-class.apple ~ .data-class.apple {
  background-color: #0ea;
}
```

This technique is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717480/css-selector-for-first-element-with-class/8539107#8539107).

Comment: Can you please update the jsbin link ? I can't get it to work  :(

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite know how to modify/fork bins. If you show the CSS you want to change I can update my answer accordingly.

Comment: I have added the css classes with the selectors also. Would the same thing be possible via a CSS4 selector?

Comment: I edited my answer. I'm not sure if it would be possible, `:nth-match()` allows combinators in the complete profile but not the CSS profile, which can be problematic.

Answer (score 0):

it is better to say having css class, not having css.
I couldn't find the appropiate selector strictly. 
Instead of this, you could use jquery and write javascript function which 
use for loop from 5th child until it finds class containing apple. You may use jquery n-th-child to select child in loop and hasClass to determine if it contains apple. 
Therefore select result by passing result to n-th-child function.

Comment: I can not used javascript for this, that's the main problem.

Answer (score 0):

It uses this test:

```
div > .data-class.apple, .data-class{.....}
```

or another use:

```
div > .apple:not(.data-class){.....}
```